# Receiving null Parcelable objects from Bundle

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I want to send a list of Parcelable objects to an activity, but I am getting null objects when receiving the objects from the activity bundle

I have a method that starts an activity, sending a list of Parcelable objects in bundle:

```
    public void openActivity(){
        ArrayList<ReportErrorVO> reports = new ArrayList<>();

        ReporteErrorVO reportError = new ReporteErrorVO();
        reportError.setTituloError("Error title 1");
        reportError.setDescripcionError("Error description 1");
        reports.add(reportError);

        reportError = new ReporteErrorVO();
        reportError.setTituloError("Error title 2");
        reportError.setDescripcionError("Error description 2");
        reports.add(reportError);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReporteErrorActivity.class);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList("reports", reports);
        intent.putExtras(args);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

My Parcelable class:

```
public class ReportErrorVO implements Parcelable {

private String titleError;
private String descriptionError;

public ReportErrorVO(Parcel in) {
    titleError = in.readString();
    descriptionError = in.readString();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(titleError);
    dest.writeString(descriptionError);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public ReportErrorVO createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ReportErrorVO(in);
    }

    public ReportErrorVO[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ReportErrorVO[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
}
```

And the activity that is called, I got:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...//Activity initializer code..

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<ReportErrorVO> reports = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        reports = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("reports");
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }       

}
```

The problem is that when I analyze the reports array, I find that althouth I got size = 2, I got the second item null (item position = 1). Note that the fist ítem of the list comes perfectly. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just faced the same problem today and I have solved by this way:

Write data:

```
 Bundle data = new Bundle();
 data.putParcelableArrayList("reports", reports);
 intent.putExtra("bundle", data);
```

Read data:

```
Bundle data = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
ArrayList<ReportErrorVO> reports= data.getParcelableArrayList("reports");
```

Hope it helps :)